# Dataframe has Everyother column timestamp, how to get it in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I import from excel that is of 'n x n' length, that looks like the following (sorry, i do not know how to easily duplicate this with code)
[image]

How do I get the timestamps into one column? Like the following (I've tried pivot)
[image]

Comment: what is the code you've tried when using pivot? and have you taken a look at [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)? Also, you can print the top 5 rows or so of the dataframe and paste the formatted text here. pictures are not good for pandas examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to extract the data by 3 columns group. Then rename the columns and add the "A,B,C" flag column and concatenate them together. See the test as below:

```
abc_list = [["2017-10-01",0,"2017-10-02",1,"2017-10-03",8],["2017-11-01",3,"2017-11-01",5,"2017-11-05",10],["2017-12-01",0,"2017-12-07",7,"2017-12-07",12]]
df = pd.DataFrame(abc_list,columns=["Time1","A","Time2","B","Time3","C"])
```

The output:

```
        Time1  A       Time2  B       Time3   C
0  2017-10-01  0  2017-10-02  1  2017-10-03   8
1  2017-11-01  3  2017-11-01  5  2017-11-05  10
2  2017-12-01  0  2017-12-07  7  2017-12-07  12
```

Then:

```
df_a=df.iloc[:,0:2].rename(columns={'Time1':'time','A':'value'})
df_a['flag']="A"
df_b=df.iloc[:,2:4].rename(columns={'Time2':'time','B':'value'})
df_b['flag']="B"
df_c=df.iloc[:,4:].rename(columns={'Time3':'time','C':'value'})
df_c['flag']="C"
df_final=pd.concat([df_a,df_b,df_c])
df_final.reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
         time  value flag
0  2017-10-01      0    A
1  2017-11-01      3    A
2  2017-12-01      0    A
3  2017-10-02      1    B
4  2017-11-01      5    B
5  2017-12-07      7    B
6  2017-10-03      8    C
7  2017-11-05     10    C
8  2017-12-07     12    C
```

This is a quit bit not a pythonic way to do it.

---

Here is another way:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','Time'),('A','Value'),('B','Time'),('B','Value'),('C','Time'),('C','Value')],names=['Group','Sub_value'])
df.columns=columns
```

Output:

```
Group               A                 B                 C
Sub_value        Time Value        Time Value        Time Value
0          2017-10-01     0  2017-10-02     1  2017-10-03     8
1          2017-11-01     3  2017-11-01     5  2017-11-05    10
2          2017-12-01     0  2017-12-07     7  2017-12-07    12
```

Run:

```
df.stack(level='Group')
```

Output:

```
Sub_value        Time  Value
  Group
0 A        2017-10-01      0
  B        2017-10-02      1
  C        2017-10-03      8
1 A        2017-11-01      3
  B        2017-11-01      5
  C        2017-11-05     10
2 A        2017-12-01      0
  B        2017-12-07      7
  C        2017-12-07     12
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one method. It is fairly easy to extend to any number of columns.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = {}

# read in pairs of columns and assign 'Category' column
dfs[i] = {i: pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols=[2*i, 2*i+1], skiprows=[0],
                           header=None, columns=['Date', 'Value']).assign(Category=j) \
             for i, j in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C'])}

# concatenate dataframes
df = pd.concat(list(dfs.values()), ignore_index=True)
```